# Rotate a linear function around a given coordinate

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have the following function representing the tangent to a circle centered around the origin which touches `(a,b)`:

$
f(x) = \frac{-ax}{b} + \frac{ \sqrt{a^2 +b^2} }
{ \cos (\arctan (\frac{a}{b})) } \cdot \frac{\left| b \right|}{b}
$

Now, say I would like to rotate this function by $\frac{\pi}{6}$.
How can I do this and still have this new function touch the `(a,b)`
coordinates?

Comment: (a,b) is not a point on circle right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since:

- $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \arctan(x) < +\frac{\pi}{2} \; \; \; \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R}$;
- $0 < \cos\theta \le 1 \; \; \; \forall \, \theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\,+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$;

it follows that:

$$
\small
\theta = \arctan(x)
\; \; \Rightarrow \; \;
x = \tan\theta
\; \; \Rightarrow \; \;
\sin\theta = x\,\cos\theta
\; \; \Rightarrow \; \;
x^2\,\cos^2\theta + \cos^2\theta = 1
\; \; \Rightarrow \; \;
\cos\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}
$$

i.e.

$$
\cos\left(\arctan(x)\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \; \; \; \forall \, x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

from which it's deduced that the function you have written is simplified in the canonical equation of a line, which doesn't need such inverse functions, although it's clear that for $f(a) = b$ there must be $x - a$, not $x$.

---

Specifically, given a circle with center $C$ and radius $r > 0$, so that a line passing through a point $P$ is tangent to the circle in $Q$:

- the line must pass through a moving point $\widetilde{P}$ and a fixed point $P$;
- the line must have a direction perpendicular to the $Q - C$ vector;

that is, the following scalar product must be identically zero:

$$
\left(\widetilde{P} - P\right) \cdot \left(Q - C\right) = 0
\; \; \; \Rightarrow \; \; \;
\left(x - x_P\right)\left(x_Q - x_C\right) + \left(y - y_P\right)\left(y_Q - y_C\right) = 0
$$

where the coordinates of the points $Q$ can be determined by solving the system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left(x_Q - x_C\right)^2 + \left(y_Q - y_C\right)^2 = r^2 \\
\left(x_Q - x_P\right)\left(x_Q - x_C\right) + \left(y_Q - y_P\right)\left(y_Q - y_C\right) = 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

from which:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& x_Q = x_C + \frac{\left(x_P - x_C\right) \pm \sqrt{\left(\lambda - 1\right)\left(y_P - y_C\right)^2}}{\lambda} \\
& y_Q = y_C + \frac{1}{\lambda}
\begin{cases}
\left(y_P - y_C\right) \mp \frac{x_P - x_C}{y_P - y_C}\sqrt{\left(\lambda - 1\right)\left(y_P - y_C\right)^2} & \text{if} \; y_P \ne y_C \\
\mp \sqrt{\left(\lambda - 1\right)\left(x_P - x_C\right)^2} & \text{if} \; y_P = y_C \\
\end{cases} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

where the ratio $\lambda = \frac{\left(x_P - x_C\right)^2 + \left(y_P - y_C\right)^2}{r^2}$ has been defined.

In particular, three cases can be highlighted:

- if $\lambda < 1$ there is no line tangent to the circle and passing through $P$;
- if $\lambda = 1$ there is only one tangent line to the circle at $Q \equiv P$;
- if $\lambda > 1$ there are two tangent lines tangent to the circle at two $Q$ and passing through $P$.

---

In light of all this, it should be clear that, regardless of the case considered, fixed $P$ the tangent lines are uniquely defined and therefore considering other tangent lines (whether with translation, rotation or roto-translation) the points $P$ of passages will also changed.

On the other hand, if by rotating this tangent line you no longer care that it's tangent to the circle, but passes only through a given point, then the information of the tangent line is superfluous and everything can be generalized in the following way.

Given a curve $\gamma$ of parametric equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = f(t) \\
y = g(t) \\
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \; \; \; \text{for} \; t \in I \subseteq \mathbb{R}
$$

in order for $\gamma$ to be rotated by $\theta \in [0,\,2\pi)$ with respect to point $C\left(x_C,\,y_C\right)$, it's necessary:

- translate $\gamma$ in such a way that $C$ coincides with the origin;
- rotate $\gamma$ by $\theta$ with respect to the origin;
- translate $\gamma$ in such a way that $C$ returns to its original position;

hence the curve $\gamma'$ of parametric equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = x_C + \left(f(t) - x_C\right)\cos\theta - \left(g(t) - y_C\right)\sin\theta \\
y = y_C + \left(f(t) - x_C\right)\sin\theta + \left(g(t) - y_C\right)\cos\theta \\
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \; \; \; \text{for} \; t \in I
$$

which only in exceptional cases can it be made explicit in a single Cartesian equation.

One of these cases is certainly the one where:

$$
f(t) = x_P + m\,t
\; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;
g(t) = y_P + n\,t
$$

with $m^2 + n^2 \ne 0$, where, eliminating the parameter $t$, it's possible to determine the Cartesian equation of the rotated line:

$$
\small
\left(x - x_C\right)\left(m\,\sin\theta + n\,\cos\theta\right) + \left(y - y_C\right)\left(n\,\sin\theta - m\,\cos\theta\right) - n\left(x_P - x_C\right) + m\left(y_P - y_C\right) = 0\,.
$$

I hope it's clear enough, good luck! ^_^